# How to store the Context?

Tags: java, android, android-context

How to store the Context in Android apps?
Often need use it in conventional classes, outside Activity(database adapters, for example).

I try save Context in static fields, but it can call memory leak.

Perhaps, will be better if I be extends Context in conventional classes and call `getApplicationContext()` inside?

Comment: best way is that you send the `Context` variable to every constructor of conventional classes(which need Context)..and store it as a private member of that class...

Answer (score 2):

the good way to do this is to pass the `Context` in the constructor. you can see in every sample code that the Context is being passed into the custom class as an argument for futur use.

i.e. in [fedorvlasov's LazyListAdapter](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) (which is very good practice on lazy loading of images from web), you can see that the constructor looks like this: `public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] data)`.

this way, every time you are outside the Activity and need to use it, you already have it stored as a field.

another way to do this (that is NOT recommended) is to use a static field that is the application Context.

```
public static final Context = getApplicationContext();
```

you put this in the launch activity and there you have it, access to the application Context all over the app's life span.

Comment: Yes, now I use static field. Can it's call memory leak?

Comment: @bvitaliyg yes, it can... you shouldn't do that.

Comment: @AlexLockwood if it's an option he should know about it. but I also added that it's not recommended.

Comment: @thepoosh actually, we are both wrong because the application context is a global singleton variable that persists across the lifetime of the application... so there's no way to really "leak" the application context. sorry I misread your original post. I'm just super-cautious on SO in even mentioning unreliable workarounds in answers, since beginners will listen to almost anything a SO user will say if they have 1000+ reputation... :P

Comment: Question, if its ok to store the application context in a global why does standard android design pass the activity or context around as a param instead? I'm designing a new `App` trying to use better OO design. So to store data to DB im using something like this  `Activity -> Helper -> DTO -> DAOImpl -> DB.` So i need to pass the `Context` all the way (via constructors) from Activity down to the DAO. it just seems silly? - Instead of storing in a `Application` static variable

Comment: there's a difference between the application Context and the single activity context. Plus, it's a bad idea to have globals